# Android transaction image between two fragment

Tags: android

I have two fragment(`FragmentA, FragmentB`), in the first fragment i have a `recycler view` , and `recycler view` contains some `images`, when i click on this image, application opens `fragmentB`, `fragmentB` have a `viewpager` , and this viewpager contains some images as well(like gallery), i want to transaction image from `fragmentA` to `viewpager` in `FragmentB`, i could not be able to do this,please help me, it is not work.

```
fragmentA recycler view on image click listner:
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
{
    fragmentB.setSharedElementEnterTransition(new DetailsTransition());
    fragmentB.setEnterTransition(new Fade());
    setExitTransition(new Fade());
    fragmentB.setSharedElementReturnTransition(new DetailsTransition());
}
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("ad_id", recyclerAdapter.dataset.get(position)._id);
fragmentB.setArguments(bundle);
getActivity()
        .getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .addSharedElement(image, "sharedImage")
        .add(R.id.main_content, fragmentB)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
```

and it is item row in FragmentA :

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ad_image"
            android:transitionName="sharedImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

and it is FramnetB viewpager:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:transitionName="sharedImage"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/placeholder_image2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/img"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This link might help: https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations

Answer (score 0):

Try below links it may help you

https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations

http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2014/12/activity-fragment-transitions-in-android-lollipop-part1.html

Comment: Link can be vanish ! This should be a comment !

Comment: Oh ok sorry for that :( @PiyushGupta

Answer (score 0):

https://medium.com/@bherbst/fragment-transitions-with-shared-elements-7c7d71d31cbb#.r0snpgei4
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Animations
 refer these two links also. These links have shared element transactions especially suitable for image transcation between Activity/Fragment